# find name, size and date modified of file inside that particular file using javascript in html file not uploaded file

Tags: javascript, html, date, size, datemodified

I want to display html file's size,name and date modified inside that html file using javascript.basically i want to fetch last date modified from server for that particular file and want to show inside that own html file for whose we are getting name and size and everything.

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i will and now if you do not have answer of question then ok.